# Empty find matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to find what's the number on the array for the 1000 value. This is my code:

```
size = linspace(420, 2200, 100000);
size1000 = find(size==1000);
```

It returns an empty variable for size 1000. If I actually change 1000 with 420 it actually returns 1 like it should. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `find` is empty because 1000 is not in the array and isn't expected to be. Using the inputs to `linspace`, your expected step size is going to be `0.0178`

```
(2200 - 420) / 100000
%   0.0178
```

With this step size and a starting value of `420`, you're never going to hit the value `1000` exactly. The closest values in the array are `1000.001` and `999.983`. If you want to identify values that are *close* to 1000, you can do something like the following instead.

```
inds = find(abs(size - 1000) < 0.01);
```

As a side-note, do not use `size` as the name of a variable since that is the name of a built-in MATLAB function and using it as a variable name can result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: I tried both lines of your code and still not getting a value

Answer (score 0):

You can also use logical indexing to simply remove all of the values below 1000, and then you know that the first component of what is left will be your answer....

```
a = size(size>1000);
a(1)
```

For what it is worth, please PLEASE do not use `size` as a variable name. `size` is an important MATLAB function to get the size of a matrix. For example,

```
>> size(randn(2,3))

ans =

     2     3
```

However, when you declare a variable named `size`, like you do in your code, you will hide this function. So now, at some point later in your code, if you called `size(randn(2,3))`, you will get the cryptic error

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
logicals.
```

These are extremely tricky to track down, so please avoid it.